# Volume properties

Tags: integration, analysis

How to go about proving this?

Let $\Omega_1 \subset \Omega_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be two bounded regions such that the boundaries of both regions are sets of measure zero. Show that the volume of $\Omega_1$ is less than or equal to the volume of $\Omega_2$.

I feel like it's pretty obvious so I don't know what to actually prove.

Thanks!